# wrong return value from service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, return-value

I have a controller that use Connection class (I made the code simpler to illustrate the problem):

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  def connect
    @flow = Flow.new(year: 2010, month: 10, day: 5)  
    @con = Connection.new(@flow)    
    @con.connect
    flash.now[:error] = "#{@con.connect}" 
  end  
end


class Connection
  def initialize(obj)    
    @obj = obj    
  end

  def connect    
    @result = [1].each do |x|        
      case         
        when (@obj.year > 1) && (@obj.day != 5)
          break "result from case1: #{@obj.day}"
        when (@obj.year > 1) && (@obj.day == 5)
          @obj.update_attributes(day: 6)
          break "result from case2 #{@obj.day}"              
      end  
    end    
    return "#{@result}"
  end
end
```

The `@flow` object matches case 2 (day: 5), but the flash shows:

`result from case1: 6`

When I test the Connection class in the console, the return value is correct.

Maybe I miss some basic concept, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the object the first time you call `connect` (`update_attributes(day: 6)`), so you get your other case the second time you call it. If you only want to call this once, save the return value in new variable and send that to the flash.

Comment: great answer, thanks for your quick replay. Now the return value is correct!